# Gradle Sync Failed: Read Timed Out

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```html
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Android Studio gives me this error, although the `gradle.properties` does not have a proxy inside it:

[image: gradle sync failed Read time out]

Comment: Please do not post image of your code, instead post you code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has been solved: deleted the gradle.properties file in home. Then, the android studio started downloading missing files..

Comment: I don't have this file. I do have a `gradle-wrapper.properties` though, is that it?

Comment: It is gradle.properties it is found in the project files. But when I had the problem, I have created another one myself as global for all projects. And, this made a problem so I deleted it..

Comment: In my case, I have known it should be a proxy issue. I checked proxy settings in Android Studio IDE Setting, and `gradle.properties` locate at project root path, But, unfortunately, forgot `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. 
Delete invalid proxy settings in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` works for me.

Comment: @Weekend oh man u saved my day. its hidden culprit ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Comment: I had the same issue in Intellij 2020.2 with gradle. Once i renamed settings.gradle , it started working again